# Access another network through a computer that is connected to two networks

Tags: routing, bridge

I have a 3 windows 7 machines that each have more than one Ethernet port. One of them is one Network A and Network B and the other 2 are only on Network B. Diagram:

```
           Network A           Network B        
         (192.168.1.x)       (10.40.101.x)      
            | -> Computer 1  <- |               
            | -> Device 1       | -> Computer 2 
            |    ...            \ -> Computer 3 
            \ -> Device 4
```

However network A has 4 devices that I would like to be able to browse to from the machines on Network B. I Imagine a bridged connection is the way to go but what do I need to do to ensure the requests to these IPs are sent toward my devices and not dropped along the way because they are in different subnets?

More info:

- I do not have the authority to change these subnets (dictated by the customer) but these are static and will not ever be changed.
- Just browsing to their IP. For instance I need to browse to
  192.168.1.27:8087 and so on. (Same port, 4 different IPs)
- No firewalls are in use on these computers.

I asked on Network Engineering and got directed here.

Answer (score 3):

Computer 1 — with NICs in both networks — should be configured dor IP routing/forwarding.

Then add static routes on computers 2 and 3 for network A with the next-hop (gateway) IP address of computer 1.

Comment: IP Routing/forwarding: Is there a standard windows 7 way to do that or would that be looking into additional software?

Comment: It’s a standard Windows (server) feature. It essentially turns the windows machine into a router.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [routers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) exist for.

Any one will do; in a pinch, you can even use a computer with two Ethernet ports and proper software.

This is built-in in Linux and in Windows Server. Not so much in client Windows systems.

Simple bridging will **not** work, because the two IP subnets are different.

Comment: I am aware of routers but am asking about the "in a pinch" scenario. I have a computer with two ports and am looking for how to set up this functionality. Before buying a router I would just run the additional Ethernet cables but I was hoping for a software solution.

Comment: On Windows Server (any version) you have RRAS; on Linux systems you have IP forwarding. But there are no built-in routing capabilities in client Windows system.

Comment: (Or rather, there are, but only in a very simple "I want to share my Internet connection with other devices" way.)